# Asp.net chart control interval not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dundas

I have asp.net chart intervel issue. I am feed data to chart like below

```
X1        Y1       X2          Y2
100    907     500        2395
100    745     500        2343
100    760     500        2403
```

Each row is a series in the chart.

In am iterating each row in code and making new serie and adding to chart

```
 series1.Points.AddXY(dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString, dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString)
 series1.Points.AddXY(dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString, dt.Rows(i)(3).ToString)
```

chart is coming like it is fine.

[image]

Now I want make intervel like 100,200,300,400, 500 (500 is max of the graph).

I tried Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 100, It did not worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in markup:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" XValueMember="ID" 
            YValueMembers="Status">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisX Interval="30" IntervalType="Number">
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```